# how to left align many rows of inline divs, that together are centered in the screen (regardless of screen size)

Tags: html, css

I have several inline divs, inside a table cell, that are all left aligned, and will wrap to the next row when there is no more space. For the most part, they look pretty good, and rearrange to properly fill the screen.

The problem is when the width of the screen is JUST SHY OF the size necessary to fit another element on the right. There is a big gap on the right side of the screen, compared to the left. It's a stylistic choice, but I am trying to figure out a way to balance the margins on both sides, no matter what the screen size is. Here is my site as it looks currently: www.bradthedesigner.com

[image: desired result, plus 2 incorrect results that I have achieved]

I am trying to get something that allows each individually to be left aligned, in a group that is centered. Instead I can either get everything left aligned (but the extra space at right looks bad, especially on small screens), or everything centered (which looks bad when there is only one item on the bottom row).

HTML

```
<center>
<div class="container">
  <div class="outerelement">
     <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outerelement">
     <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
 <div class="outerelement">
     <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outerelement">
     <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outerelement">
     <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
       <div class="outerelement">
     <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outerelement">
     <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outerelement">
     <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</center>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
text-align:center;
border:2px solid black;
}

.outerelement
{
width:216px;
height:216px;
display: inline-block;
}

.element
{
background-color:#999999;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius:16px;
}
```

Looking at the code I've got online, I see that I switched to tables, because I was more familiar with their behavior and borders for debugging. Here is me recreating my results with divs though... I've tried using `<center>` outside, `align=center` inside, and all sorts of CSS styles that came up on other searches through stack overflow.

I've been beating my head against a wall, and can't seem to find any-one doing something similar. It doesn't seem too crazy does it? Basically it boils down to, if the contents of a div are too big to fit, of course it should wrap... but why then does the div stay the width of the screen if the contents that fit on any row don't reach that far? A table with rows and columns would work, but that isn't able to adapt to different screen resolutions or window re-sizing, is it?

Comment: Please post an [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: You can view my source in the link www.bradthedesigner.com that I gave, but I will update the question with some portion of that code.

Comment: I updated the question with some of the code I have tried. I can add <center> outside, or text-align:center inside the outermost div, but that always seems to just center everything, rather than just the outer div. 

I have managed to get the outermost div to center itself using Ahmad's suggestion, but the div still has extra space beyond the last sub item, and therefore still appears lopsided as a result.

Thank you for your patience, and your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well from the image you are posting I can tell the problem ...

You want to whole block that contain the small blocks to be horizontally aligned (equal spaces on each side) and the inline divs to be aligned to the left ...

Your first attempt is the default behavior (the inline blocks are wrapping to the next line but no proper alignment for the container)

Your second attempt was to set `text-align: center` to the container which is perfect but it won't align the last line as you desire ...

To achieve what you want, you need to wrap all the inline divs in a single `div` with predefined width ... Something like

```
.wrapper-div {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The `margin: 0 auto` declaration will force the `div` to be horizontally aligned as you want.

Comment: so, playing around with JSfiddle, your code looks like its working right... until I remove the 500 width. If I don't specify, or instead say something like 90% or 100%, you will notice how it is still lopsided.

https://jsfiddle.net/to0jLfj7/2/

Comment: Is it not possible to shrink the boundaries of the table or div, to the items that already fit without wrapping... so that the body as a whole could be centered?

the div properly fits to the content, as long as it is only one row tall. As soon as it wraps, the div seems to stretch to the width of the screen. This confuses me!

Answer (score 1):

When you render out the blocks, render out empty placeholders that aren't visible but take up the space of the missing elements on the last row.  This will push the existing elements on the last row to the left.

Comment: Although this is very clever, I would have to first know how many are fitting on each row. Is there a way to do this, when the screen resolution can vary, or even be resized?

Comment: You have a couple options.  1) set your container to a fixed width and center it 2) have a javascript on page resize handler to calculate the width and determine the empty space based on container width and item width and number of items.  If you are going with 2, you don't really need extra placeholders, just add margin to the last item to take up the space.

Comment: Thank you. I did come to that conclusion, of either having fixed width, or javascript be my only solutions available. I had hoped there was some sort of css concepts I didn't understand that would make it work, but oh well. 

I'm new to posting on SO, but it seems like you should get credit for the answer, even though your answer currently is not what I am using. Is there any chance you want to update it to reflect my 2 options you just mentioned?